# get address from reverse geocoding

Tags: iphone, maps, geocoding

in my application, I got a map that show the location of the user. But I also need to get the exact address of where he is and put it in a string.

How does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [MKReverseGeocoder](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKReverseGeocoder_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  Look at the Apple sample app [CurrentAddress](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/CurrentAddress/Introduction/Intro.html).
The placemark object passed into didFindPlacemark has the address fields which you can put into a string.